# Maven packaging web application

Tags: maven-2

i removed one un-used dependency from pom.xml of the project which had packaging of war kind.Even after removing it, it is getting bundled under lib folder.
Why is this so?
Appreciate your inputs

Comment: Do you mean the removed dependency stills gets bundled within your WAR file? I suggest you post your POM file so people can help out.

Answer (score 0):

execute following command to see your actual pom

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

or outout it to a file

```
mvn help:effective-pom > effective-pom.xml
```

now go through the generated `effective-pom.xml`